# Calling and serializing FB feed

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, facebook-graph-api

I am calling FB feed from multiple FB pages with

```
/posts?ids=OI.Plavipingvin,217384491624554&limit=5&fields=message,created_time,id
```

This is the feed I get:

```
{
   "217384491624554": {
     "data": [
       {
         "message": "Obećanje i zavjet položeni. Dobrodošli u OI Javor ❤",
         "created_time": "2017-01-08T01:05:25+0000",
         "id": "217384491624554_1575515795811410"
       },
       {
         "message": "Zimovanje u punom tijeku :-)",
         "created_time": "2017-01-04T10:06:57+0000",
         "id": "217384491624554_1572127976150192"
       }
     ],
     "paging": {
       "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/217384491624554/posts?fields=message,created_time,id&limit=2&format=json&since=1483837525&access_token=EAACEdEose0cBAMlhIYetCMo0m83Jdo3F7rk4NYmm47Q1T19UDxlKhMQnjDW4Mmelqu3vzTITnVA7E0ZBgl6jDmlHC8J7ZCX4TW2xB0xoHIySu3MK5d9yUWjqMLdUrRab9KTfH1WyzpEfIbxG7JlhPnZACfiFWFfhvO9vrAZCrAZDZD&__paging_token=enc_AdB6GEshkXkXuRJcuiHCF1aoS4rK7Myp3P6mFZAUFeZAPbRVdtmihE7UAOIlFDuTjVKHvmBeiMLmWfIZBfCER7cYrS08kccUDDoixEb2ZABASuwAigZDZD&__previous=1",
       "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/217384491624554/posts?fields=message,created_time,id&limit=2&format=json&access_token=EAACEdEose0cBAMlhIYetCMo0m83Jdo3F7rk4NYmm47Q1T19UDxlKhMQnjDW4Mmelqu3vzTITnVA7E0ZBgl6jDmlHC8J7ZCX4TW2xB0xoHIySu3MK5d9yUWjqMLdUrRab9KTfH1WyzpEfIbxG7JlhPnZACfiFWFfhvO9vrAZCrAZDZD&until=1483524417&__paging_token=enc_AdBeiIQZBem7NbobO8r183HtpPnZAOY6CRyehrr8uDJZBXkSS5kKS3YpqdmosFZCGZBobXwMnKW4hEsAIEZCjhYCAL2NdAX7ZCZAyWHZB7GhQCS0IQIqEZBwZDZD"
     }
   },
   "OI.Plavipingvin": {
     "data": [
       {
         "message": "Sretnu novu godinu želi vam Uprava odreda. Budite sretni i zadovoljni. I naravno - pripravni za nove avanture!   ",
         "created_time": "2017-01-02T10:07:27+0000",
         "id": "379925365427474_1274199672666701"
       },
       {
         "message": "Jutros na Omanovcu. Imamo snijeg! :)",
         "created_time": "2016-12-28T07:03:07+0000",
         "id": "379925365427474_1269358063150862"
       }
     ],
     "paging": {
       "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/379925365427474/posts?fields=message,created_time,id&limit=2&format=json&since=1483351647&access_token=EAACEdEose0cBAMlhIYetCMo0m83Jdo3F7rk4NYmm47Q1T19UDxlKhMQnjDW4Mmelqu3vzTITnVA7E0ZBgl6jDmlHC8J7ZCX4TW2xB0xoHIySu3MK5d9yUWjqMLdUrRab9KTfH1WyzpEfIbxG7JlhPnZACfiFWFfhvO9vrAZCrAZDZD&__paging_token=enc_AdDjsccg8E9vHw7XXgXW22NDK0l3MH4mR5XvwXidebNK2Kb8bdewjPiTLGDP8yNw8rpcHYT8VME5YPxLhZC0QZCjdLkHBYJCQZBYdQQWsfmhmC2yQZDZD&__previous=1",
       "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/379925365427474/posts?fields=message,created_time,id&limit=2&format=json&access_token=EAACEdEose0cBAMlhIYetCMo0m83Jdo3F7rk4NYmm47Q1T19UDxlKhMQnjDW4Mmelqu3vzTITnVA7E0ZBgl6jDmlHC8J7ZCX4TW2xB0xoHIySu3MK5d9yUWjqMLdUrRab9KTfH1WyzpEfIbxG7JlhPnZACfiFWFfhvO9vrAZCrAZDZD&until=1482908587&__paging_token=enc_AdDZCnhwlRCxibv0aGr141JPdbcHcJssKFjhtToaTpfqKbZABvo5g0fhtCgDpwCNoMBopGK4o0CJxXzRyRJKxLCqOh0belZCXBQdTNZCEF5eRuu6agZDZD"
     }
   }
 }
```

My current FBClass:

```
Public Class FBData
    Public Property data As New List(Of FBFeed)
End Class

Public Class FBFeed
    Public Property message As String
    Public Property created_time As DateTime
    Public Property id As String
End Class
```

Current GetPosts function, ordering and showing result:

```
Public Shared Function GetPosts( accessToken As String ) As FBData

    Dim APIlink As String = "https://graph.facebook.com/posts?ids=OI.Plavipingvin,217384491624554&limit=5&fields=message,created_time,id&access_token=" & accessToken

    Dim client As New WebClient()
    client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
    Dim strJson As [String] = client.DownloadString(APIlink)

    Dim result As FBData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of FBData)( strJson )

    Return result

End Function

Dim array1 As FBData = GetPosts ( accessToken )

For Each Msg As FBFeed In array1.data.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.created_time)
    Response.Write( i & ". " & Msg.created_time & "<br />" )
Next
```

What FBClass should I use for serialization of this JSON and how to read FBClass list (or array)? I don't need User-ID or data tags.

Comment: @MrGadget - I have another problem, please if you can help me with this (I have 20 page IDs to call, and then show sorted JSON - this would be more effective way to call them in one API call and then sort one JSON array)

Comment: For clarity of the question, please add your current code here.

Comment: I have changed the question with current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While my other answer works, it's a bit clumsy if one has a bunch of feeds to deal with, so this should be a more effective answer.  I chose not to edit the previous answer because it's valid depending on one's needs.

Given this revised class structure...

```
Public Class FBFeed
    Public Property data As Datum()
    Public Property paging As Paging
End Class

Public Class Datum
    Public Property message As String
    Public Property created_time As DateTime
    Public Property id As String
End Class

Public Class Paging
    Public Property previous As String
    Public Property [next] As String
End Class
```

...and this revised GetPosts method...

```
Public Shared Function GetPosts(accessToken As String, ParamArray args() As String) As Dictionary(Of String, FBFeed)
    'Dim APIlink As String = "https://graph.facebook.com/posts?ids=OI.Plavipingvin,217384491624554&limit=5&fields=message,created_time,id&access_token=" & accessToken

    Dim Ids As String = Join(args, ",")
    Dim APITemplate As String = "https://graph.facebook.com/posts?ids={0}&limit=5&fields=message,created_time,id&access_token={1}"
    Dim APIlink As String = String.Format(APITemplate, Ids, accessToken)

    Using client As New WebClient()
        client.Encoding = Text.Encoding.UTF8
        Dim strJson As String = client.DownloadString(APIlink)

        Return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, FBFeed))(strJson)
    End Using
End Function
```

...the usage in the page request handler becomes...

```
Dim MyData As New List(Of Datum)

Dim IdList As New List(Of String)
IdList.Add("OI.Plavipingvin")
IdList.Add("217384491624554")

With GetPosts("Access Token Here", IdList.ToArray)
    ' We have a Dictionary(Of String, FBFeed) we can flatten with SelectMany
    '   and consolidate the Datum arrays into the MyData List(Of Datum) above
    MyData.AddRange(.Values.SelectMany(Function(x) x.data).ToList())
End With

For Each Msg As Datum In MyData.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.created_time)
    Response.Write(Msg.message & ". " & Msg.created_time & "<br />")
Next
```

Comment: Great, I didn't believe it is possible. You have helped me a lot! I have many FB IDs (26 IDs) and this second solution is great - making this the answer! I need one suggestion- what do you mean is the best way to feed this IDs to APIlink string?

Comment: Updated GetPosts and Usage. ParamArray allows that you could also call GetPosts with a variable number of ID strings, e.g. `GetPosts("SomeToken", "OI.Plavipingvin", "217384491624554", ..., "SomeOtherID")`

Comment: The `APITemplate` has substitution placeholders for `StringFormat` to replace. Additionally, I wrapped the `WebClient` with `Using` as it's Disposable.

Comment: That's it! I have had problem with calling my list. Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The class structure would have to look like this:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Public Class FBData
    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="217384491624554")>
    Public Property Feed_217384491624554 As FBFeed

    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="OI.Plavipingvin")>
    Public Property Feed_OIPlavipingvin As FBFeed
End Class

Public Class FBFeed
    Public Property data As Datum()
    Public Property paging As Paging
End Class

Public Class Datum
    Public Property message As String
    Public Property created_time As DateTime
    Public Property id As String
End Class

Public Class Paging
    Public Property previous As String
    Public Property [next] As String
End Class
```

Update: Usage:

```
Dim array1 As FBData = GetPosts ( accessToken )

Dim MyData As New List(Of Datum)
MyData.AddRange(array1.Feed_217384491624554.data)
MyData.AddRange(array1.Feed_OIPlavipingvin.data)

For Each Msg As Datum In MyData.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.created_time)
    Response.Write(Msg.message & ". " & Msg.created_time & "<br />")
Next
```

Comment: That was it, but... how can I order data based on created_time? Is that even possible? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Usage added to my answer.